# Mock an Admin Controller for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am working with ASP.NET Core 2.0, using xUnit and Moq to create unit tests for administrative functions. I have an AdminController.cs that uses dependency injection for the following within its constructor

```
private UserManager<AppUser> userManager;
private IUserValidator<AppUser> userValidator;
private IPasswordValidator<AppUser> passwordValidator;
private IPasswordHasher<AppUser> passwordHasher;
private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
private SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager;
```

I try to arrange them in the following manner in my unit test

```
// Arrange
Mock<EFRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<EFRepository>();
var userStoreMock = new Mock<IUserRoleStore<AppUser>>();
var userManager = new UserManager<AppUser>(userStoreMock.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
AppUser user = new AppUser();

var roleStoreMock = new Mock<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
var userValidator = new Mock<IUserValidator<AppUser>>();
var passwordValidator = new Mock<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>>();
var passwordHasher = new Mock<IPasswordHasher<AppUser>>();
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStoreMock.Object, null, null, null, null, null);
var signInManager = new Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

//THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
AdminController controller = new AdminController(userManager, userValidator.Object, passwordValidator.Object, passwordHasher.Object, roleManager, signInManager.Object);
```

I get the following error:

`Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager 
Could not find a parameterless constructor.`

I have not yet been able to find a proper way of mocking a `SignInManager` that works

I've been trying to work with the method below without success:

```
private Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>> GetMockSignInManager()
{
    var mockUsrMgr = GetMockUserManager();
    var mockAuthMgr = new Mock<AuthenticationManager>();
    var mockContextAssosor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var mockClaimsFactory = new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser>>();
    //i am unclear on how to mock the options
    var opts = new Mock<IOptions<>>();
    var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<AppUser>>>();
    //namespace for IAuthenicationSchemeProvider is not recognized
    var scheme = new Mock<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
    //return new Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>>(mockUsrMgr.Object, mockAuthMgr.Object...and so on);
}
```

Comment: Stop coupling your code to implementation concerns. Abstract those out behind interfaces.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't quite follow; could you show an example of what you're suggesting? I've been trying to follow the text Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>> GetMockSignInManager()
{
    var mockUsrMgr = new UserManager<AppUser>(userStoreMock.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    var ctxAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
    var mockClaimsPrinFact = new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser>>();
    var mockOpts = new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>();
    var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<AppUser>>>();

    return new Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>>(mockUsrMgr.Object, ctxAccessor, mockClaimsPrinFact.Object, mockOpts.Object, mockLogger.Object);
}
```